# Script to find distro groups with limited senders (and who)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Looking for a PS script to display not only those distribution groups that AcceptMessageOnlyFrom BUT also display who those senders are ("Only senders in the following list").

This script, found elsewhere, gets me part of the way there:

get-distributiongroup “DisplayName” | select -expandproperty AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom | select name

Answer (score 0):

This can be done:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize 10 | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $group = $_

    $group.AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom |
    Foreach-Object {
        $recipient = Get-Recipient $_

        [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
            GroupName = $group.Name;
            AllowedSender = $recipient.PrimarySMTPAddress
        }
    }
}
```

Change the resultsize to Unlimited or whatever is appropriate for you.  You can further export this to CSV if you'd like.